# Questions about __attribute__ and noinline (GCC)

Tags: c++, gcc

Can tell somebody what this mean in C++? (is in front of a function)
Also how I find something about this issue.

```
__attribute__ ((noinline))
```

Thank you . Regards

Comment: It means that the compiler should not inline calls to that function. In "machine talk", it means it forces the compiler to store that function at one place and always make a call to it from all call sites: if left to itself, it may choose to include the code of that function to the place where it is called instead, in some call sites -- or even all, if the function is small.

Comment: @fge do you want to post that as an answer? so he can set it as the correct answer for future visitors?

Comment: @DumbProducts too late :p

Comment: @fge you were the first to comment, maybe not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC defines a number of different non-standard [function attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) used for indicating special features of functions.  These are usually used for optimization or dealing with platform-specific features.

In this case, the `noinline` attribute means "don't inline this function under any circumstances", when the optimizer might otherwise inline it.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much what the name of this attribute implies. As a kind of heavy optimization, the compiler may chose to inline smaller functions in order to avoid the overhead of function calls. If you don't want your function to be inlined for some reason, you can use this [nonstandard attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) to prevent the compiler from doing this optimization.

> It is in front of a function

To learn how GCC attributes are organized syntactically, see [this guide.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html)